# Localized geocoding options in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, mapkit, core-location, clgeocoder

With iOS 6 can we still use Google's API to geocode addresses? I vaguely recall that Google's licensing requires the results to be displayed on Google maps, which is obviously not possible in iOS 6.

I have found the built in CLGeocoder to be hit & miss, often not returning results for the simplest of searches.

Another thing I'm looking for is geocoding / reverse geocoding with results in the local language. Is this possible with CLGeocoder?

Comment: I was under the impression the results could be used provided you credited the use of the Google service with a logo or some such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to display the Goolge Maps as an overlay. Here an example from github

https://github.com/mladjan/GoogleMapsOverlayiOS

Comment: Interesting... I can't believe this is approved by Apple but I'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the Google API for geocoding requires results to be displayed on a Google map.

CLGeocoder result quality hopefully will improve rapidly now that users are giving Apple feedback for maps.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. That is something I can live with, however I do require localized geocoding, do you happen to know if this is possible?

Comment: I am not sure, but you might look around for third parties that can supply more accurate data for a fee...